# Schedule a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 Workflow

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am in the process of puting together a custom workflow activity to be used in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0

What I would like to ultimatly acheive is configure a workflow that runs on a schedueled basis i.e run every 2 hours Monday to Friday, rather than on a particular "CRM event" like create, delete status change ect.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Maybe schedule it outside of crm?

**Edit 1:**

What we are doing is processing rows in a staging table that gets generated from a front-end site.  We are creating contact/account and opportunity records in CRM based on the data captured from the front-end.

The more I think about it the more I'm thinking that using workflow is possibly not the best solution?

What about a using a windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow was not best option for this situation due to the following:

- Can't schedule it to run
- The process can only be triggered by a CRM create, update or similar message

I went with a combination of the following:
A SQL CLR sproc that gets called on an UPDATE trigger on the staging table.  The CLR sproc calls a webservice that generates CRM contacts/accounts.  That way the front-end site can create records and set a "ready to process" flag once all data has been entered.

The requirement changed from a schedule solution to real time processing (well not ACTUALLY real time). The process needs to run as records are entered from the front end site.

Hope all that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

A windows workflow using the CRM webservices is one option, a better option would be to change your webform to access the CRM webservce adn enter the data directly.

if you really want to use workflows you can download a tool from http://www.patrickverbeeten.com/pages/TechnicalNet/MicrosoftCrm/PeriodicWorkflows.aspx?id=23 that you install on your CRM server and it allows you to use windows sheduled tasks to triger them.